# Determining position of items and triggering scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Current code:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gridnik/2s1w6cbL/

```
<div class="fixed">
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have a fixed div (with background image, "cover" and "opacity" property) on top of everything and a content div beneath that. What I want is; when the user scrolls down, top div scrolls first. When top div slides out from the viewport, content div starts to scroll.

Here's a quick animation to make it clear:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this good for your request ?

```
$(window).on("mousewheel", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.fixed').animate({
                marginTop:'+=30px'
            }, 0);
            if($('.fixed').offset().top >= $(window).height(){$(this).unbind('mousewheel'); 
$('.content').css('position','absolute')}
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hxqyz39p/

**Update:** http://jsfiddle.net/hxqyz39p/1/

Comment: Thanks but that's not exactly what I want.

Comment: What exactly i miss ?

Comment: Sorry, I should give more information. Top div is not scrolling horizontally. Feels like some white div slides in from the top of "top" div. 
And also it irreversible. I mean when I scroll the top of the page, "top" div is not slides in.

Comment: Let me get this: When the user loads in your page, what is supposed to see first? The text on white background or the background image with text? In your animation posted  as example, the background image is hidding on top and slides in when the user scrolls down after the content has reached the end. In your fiddle, i see both image background and text prezend.

Comment: I want something that works exactly like my animation;

When the user loads in my page, they supposed to see "top" div (with background image) first. When user starts to scrolls, "top" div starts to slide out first. But text div stands still. When "top" div slides out completely from the viewport, text div starts to scroll naturally.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with ".slideUp" and "slideDown" method?
Like I said before, "fixed" div is not scrolling to the top of the viewport with your solution.

Comment: If you want this project to be done EXACTLY and not ''something"  like in your animation example, please say it clearly. In the animation example, I see the 'fixed' div is crossing the top when is scrolling up. if that's what you want to do or you want more  then that, write it clearly with all the details you can give it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite complex problem to solve in JS/jQuery alone.

I suggest taking a look at the CSS implementation of `position: sticky`, however, it’s not something that is widely supported by browsers. (But in my experience it’s the best technique to solve this. And it works on iOS, which is a big plus.)

Here’s information about browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

And here’s a polyfill for the other browsers: https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky (with demos)

**Update:** Here’s a proof of concept (works in Firefox and Safari): http://jsfiddle.net/2s1w6cbL/2/

Comment: Thanks Marius, it looks promising.

Comment: Ok, happy to help. Reading your question again, I realized my example probably doesn't do exactly what you're looking for, but with some tweaking it should :)